# Why doesn't SelectedValue Show Up In Intellisense For DropDownLists?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

It doesn't show up in aspx pages, but it does in codebehind.

Are we not supposed to be using it?
Is it not there to make the intellisense list more manageable?
Did they screw up?

If I recall it wasn't there in previous versions as well...  Anyone know the story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the declaration for the property includes `[BrowsableAttribute(false)]`. This was added starting in .NET 3.5.

> Members marked with the [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.browsableattribute.aspx) constructor's *browsable* parameter set to **false** are not appropriate for design-time editing and therefore are not displayed in a visual designer.

My guess is since it is also settable in the item, it causes confusion.